# Error in Android Studio when building bundle: "Task :app:mapDebugSourceSetPaths FAILED"

Tags: java, android, flutter, android-studio

I am facing an issue in Android Studio while trying to build a bundle for my project. The error message I am encountering is as follows:

```
Task :app:mapDebugSourceSetPaths FAILED
Execution failed for task ':app:mapDebugSourceSetPaths'.
> Error while evaluating property 'extraGeneratedResDir' of task ':app:mapDebugSourceSetPaths'.
   > Failed to calculate the value of task ':app:mapDebugSourceSetPaths' property 'extraGeneratedResDir'.
      > Querying the mapped value of provider(java.util.Set) before task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices' has completed is not supported
```

```
Execution failed for task ':app:mapDebugSourceSetPaths'.
> Error while evaluating property 'extraGeneratedResDir' of task ':app:mapDebugSourceSetPaths'.
   > Failed to calculate the value of task ':app:mapDebugSourceSetPaths' property 'extraGeneratedResDir'.
      > Querying the mapped value of provider(java.util.Set) before task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices' has completed is not supported
```

I have tried to find a solution by searching online, but so far, I haven't been able to resolve this issue.

Steps to Reproduce:

Open Android Studio.
Attempt to build a bundle for the project.

I would appreciate any insights or guidance on how to resolve this issue. Thank you!